# How to get section and subsection with upshape (normal) numbers

Tags: sectioning, numbering

In my thesis I wanna to get the section and subsection numbers in upshape not italic while i am getting it in italic shape. As per my thesis requirement i have to be in upshape i.e

*1.1* Section

*1.1.1* Subsection

But I wanna to be like this

1.1 Section

1.1.1 Subsection

Comment: Usualy, the default behavior is to have these numbers upright. Could you add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) reproducing the problem?

Comment: when i am using the document class book then it is upright but by changing to document class thesis then it is italic i.e.                                               
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, s4hao,coverboxed,notocintoc,etoc,newgbkfonts,sloppy,openany,twoside]{book}    while by adding some packages document class [book] is not working. so for that reason i am using document class [thesis] which creates that mentioned problem

Comment: As far as I remember there are multiple documentclasses called thesis out there. Which one do you use? Also did your institution provide the class file meaning that you absolutely have to use it or did you just found it  decided to use that class?

Comment: @ leandriis My institution did not provide me any file but i am using the                                       \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,s4hao,coverboxed,notocintoc,etoc,newgbkfonts,sloppy,openany,twoside]{thesis}

Comment: there are thousands of different classes all called thesis.cls. look in the file (the log of your document will show the full path to thesis.cls then just look where it uses `\it` or `\itshape` in section definitions and change it not to do that in a local copy.

Comment: @ David Carlisle what do you mean by the full path of thesis. I checked it but didn't find in section \it or \itshape

Comment: if your document is `myfile.tex` then `myfile.log` will show the  full path to every file input, something like `(/usr/local/texlive-local/zzz/zzz/thesis.cls` whatever code you want to change will be in there

Comment: @David Carlisle  can't find is it in the installed program or somewhere else or in online I am using an installed program Miktex 2.9

Comment: as I say, your log will show the path to the file

Comment: @ David Carlisle can't find it. Is i check it all but no way. sorry for bothering you need help for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109674/discussion-between-jhon-and-david-carlisle).